# ERROR "Insert or update on table "Role" violates foreign key constraint "Role_created_by_User_fk" when using sequelize cli

Tags: node.js, postgresql, foreign-keys, seed, sequelize-cli

I have never used `sequelize cli` before. I need to set up this project which uses `PostgreSQL` and perform some tasks in it. When I got this project folder it already contained a folder of migration, modal, and seeders therefore I figured out that I only need to run some commands. I have executed these commands step by step,

`1)npx sequelize-cli db:create`

`2)npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`

`3)npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all`

In the third command, I'm getting this error

> "Insert or update on table "Role" violates foreign key constraint
> "Role_created_by_User_fk"

I have tried to search this error but found no answer, I figured this myself that maybe if I will seed the user table first this error might not occur but that doesn't work either and my tables are still empty.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. For code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This term, foreign key constraint means that PostgreSQL wants to ensure that whenever you set up the foreign key, it tries to reference a record that actually exists inside the users table.

In this case, there is no match so you are ending up with an error.

Now this is a very good feature you have, it ensures that you are not going to insert data into your database that doesn’t make sense at all.

So it looks like you are going to have to look into your `Role` table and `User` table and ensure that the `created_by_User` foreign key actually matches the id of a user on that `User` table.

So in other words you are inserting data into that Role table for a user that does not exist.